# JAVA JPA Predicate - Retrieve same column value in OR condition

Tags: java, jpa, predicate

I am trying to retrieve the data from Table TABLE_A, Table Table_A contain Column BB_NUM.

- I need to write the expression in JPA BooleanExpression,
- Needed to generate below SQL Query from JPA predicate logic:

  ```
  **Select * from TABLE_A where BB_NUM like 'GA22'OR BB_NUM like 'GA33';**
  ```
- And this GA22 GA33 are comes dynamically, So this where condition is dynamically added.
- Below code have write to dynamically create where condition in predicate expression, but this code is not working,

  ```
      boolean firstTime = true;
      str = "GA22GA33";
      BooleanExpression ent = null;
                      for (String array : str.split("GA")) {
                          if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(array)) {
                              if (firstTime) {
                                  ent = qTABLE_A.BB_NUM.containsIgnoreCase("GA" + array.trim());
                                  firstTime = false;
                              } else {
                                  ent.or(qTABLE_A.BB_NUM.containsIgnoreCase("GA" + array.trim()));
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      expressions.add(ent);
  ```

Above code is works like SQL,

```
**Select * from TABLE_A where BB_NUM like 'GA22';**
```

need to work

```
**Select * from TABLE_A where BB_NUM like 'GA22' or BB_NUM like 'GA33';**
```

Comment: what does `this code is not working` mean? What is the expected result? What happens instead? (also please try to format the question better, since it's sooo hard to read)

Comment: Trying to generater " Select * from TABLE_A where BB_NUM like 'GA22' or BB_NUM like 'GA33' or BB_NUM like 'GA44' " in JPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like:

```
else {
    ent = ent.or(qTABLE_A.BB_NUM.containsIgnoreCase("GA" + array.trim()));
}
```

Also you can substitute `if (firstTime)` with `if (ent == null)`